# How to link two tables with a pivot table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, hyperlink, pivot

Hey so a bit of an overview of the project i want to do. I want to show the user's teams.

When the  user logged in and opened the `viewteams` page. He must show teams he joined/created. To do so i ve done the below processes...

my ViewTeamController

```
{
    public function index()
    {
      $user=User::first();
      $teams=Team::all();
      $user->teams()->attach($teams);
      return view('teams.viewteams',compact('teams'));
    }

    public function store()
    {

    }

}
```

my User model

```
    public function teams(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class,'team_user','teams_id','users_id');
    }
```

my Team model

```
  public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'team_user','teams_id','users_id');
  }
```

my migration of the pivot table

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('team_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('users_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('teams_id');



            $table->index('users_id');
            $table->index('teams_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

web.php routes

```
Route::get('/viewteams','ViewTeamController@index');
Route::post('/viewteams','ViewTeamController@store');
```

my viewteams.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header"><h2 style="text-align:center;">Your Teams</h2></div>


                <div class="card-body">
                  @foreach ($teams as $team)
                    @foreach($team->users as $user)
                      {{$user->org_name}}
                      @endforeach
                  @endforeach


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

my other controller for Creating a team

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Team;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CreateTeamController extends Controller
{
  public function index(Request $request)
  {
    return view('teams.createteams');

  }

  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    $team=Team::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('home');
  }


}
```

all my routes

```
Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('auth/login');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/viewteams','ViewTeamController@index');
Route::post('/viewteams','ViewTeamController@store');

Route::get('/createteams','CreateTeamController@index');

Route::post('/createteams','CreateTeamController@store') ;

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: Can you show where you assign user and team each other

Comment: What do you mean sir?

Comment: How you attach a user to a team. Can you show those codes ?

Comment: i edited my controller but  what i did there doesnt work because i only get the user's name and many times

Comment: Because whenever you open view team page you attach first user to every team ?

Comment: @miken32 I only want to show him the right way through  which teams can be assigned to user  by using sync so that teams can be accessed using  relations.  But ya my answer is not appropriate for this question I will delete my comment I didn't understood his question well

Answer (score 1):

To achieve currents users teams, first you should get authenticated user id using Auth facade.

After that you can load joined teams for user, using 'with' method. It loads teams relationships.

ViewTeamController

```
public function index()
{
     $user = User::with('teams')->find(Auth::id());

     return view('teams.viewteams',compact('user'))
}
```

viewteams.blade.php

```
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header"><h2 style="text-align:center;">Your Teams</h2></div>


                <div class="card-body">
                  @foreach ($user->teams as $team)
                    {{ $team->name }}
                  @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: no its not on purpose i just found that code on the internet and i modified it a bit but i dont understand it to be honest.I just want the current user that is logged in to see the teams he is a part of.

Comment: It gave me another error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found  .

Comment: you can either import Auth facade from `Illuminate\Support\Facade\Auth` or you can just add backslash to auth facade like `\Auth`

Comment: it seems that i am missing support/auth class and i need to install it with composer but when i do i get an error

Comment: you dont need to install, laravel comes with those facades. I just made a typo in namespace. add next line beginning of ViewTeamController. `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

Comment: you are right it shows now but still it shows all the teams and a lot of times .

Comment: it because of you were used to attach all teams to user repeatedly when user view the teams page. You have to clear your team_user table or remove dublicates.

Comment: i literally did nothing , only  " php artisan migrate:fresh " and when i register with a new uiser and add a new team it doesnt add it in my database table team_user

Comment: have you attach user to any team after you create new user and team ?

Comment: no because last time i attached the first user with all the teams... i want to only attach the user with the team he created

Comment: so did yo do it ? did you attach the user to the team he created ?

Comment: $user=User::first();
      $teams=Team::first();
      $user->teams()->attach($teams); But this only attaches the first user to the first team right ?

Comment: I will remove my answer. Please stop texting me

Comment: LOL help vampires are fun ‍♂️. There may be a language barrier here as well, with what "attach" means to the OP. Just a note: I'd recommend using `Auth::user()->with("teams")` instead. It saves the extra database lookup, since you already have the user object available.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to revisit and update the code which stores data to the users table and the teams user. The easiest way to store the data in a way which populates the pivot table is to use the `sync()` method as described at https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

I'm making some assumptions about names and relationships, buy you may have something like this:

```
$user = User::find(2);
$user->teams()->sync([4,5]);
```

In this case, you would put into the pivot table a record for `user_id of 2 and team_id of 4`, and a second record for a `user_id of 2 and a team_id of 5`.

If you want to share more code showing route definitions and controllers for how you are currently handling things, we can help with any more specific implementation questions.

Comment: I edited my post with the things you asked or at least i hope thats what you asked!  I am a total newbie so i am browsing endlessly to understand how to do what i want and make it work but i dont understand most of the things . Like this sync command you explained it nicely but i want the user that is logged in right now to see the teams he is participating in.